# Обновление источника данных

Tags: c#, winforms, ado.net

Если правильно понимаю customersRow это строка с желаемыми изменениями вводимая пользователем, которая должна изменить строку в источнике.

Объясните, пожалуйста что такое переменные @FName, @LName и тд ?
Объясниете, пожалуйста, как связанны между собой ReadOnly, первичный ключ и

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
 
namespace Updates
{
    static class CustomersUpdates
    {
        private static void ChangeCustomers(DataRow customersRow)
        {
            string connectionString = @"Data Source=WIN-9VNS32J8479\IVAN;Initial Catalog=ShopDB;Integrated Security=True";
 
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
 
            string commandString = "UPDATE Customers " +
                                   "SET FName = @FName," +
                                   "LName = @LName," +
                                   "MName= @Mname," +
                                   "Address1 = @Address1," +
                                   "Address2 = @Address2," +
                                   "City = @City," +
                                   "Phone = @Phone," +
                                   "DateInSystem = @DateInSystem " +
                                   "WHERE CustomerNo = @CustomerNo"; //обновятся все данные независимо от того какие записи изменим. 
            //Но изменится только та вставка где CustomerNo = нашему входному параметру (видимо который прописан в источнике).
 
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
 
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandString, connection); 
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CustomerNo", customersRow[0]); 
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("FName", customersRow[1]);      
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("LName", customersRow[2]);     
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("MName", customersRow[3]);     
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Address1", customersRow[4]);   
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Address2", customersRow[5]);   
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("City", customersRow[6]);      
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Phone", customersRow[7]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("DateInSystem", customersRow[8]);
 
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            customersRow.AcceptChanges();
        }
 
        public static void ChangeCustomers(DataTable customers) //перегрузка метода описанного выше
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in customers.Rows)
            {
                if (row.RowState == DataRowState.Modified) 
                    ChangeCustomers(row);                   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробую вам ответить.

@FName - имя ,обычное сокращение First Name

@LName - фамилия, обычное сокращение Last Name

@MName - среднее или промежуточное имя, обычное сокращение Middle Name

@Address1 - первая строка в адресе

@Address2 - ...

@City - город в адресе

@Phone - номер телефона

@DateInSystem - системное время

Свойства объекта ReadOnly не изменяются после инициализации, первичный ключ он же primary, уникальный идентификатор записи в таблице обычно автоинкремент, но может и не быть им. Связь такая чтоб никто не менял ключ в ручную. Думаю как-то так.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ. Я несколько не точно сформулировал. Непонятно откуда берутся данные переменные

Comment: Если ответ полезен, то можете пометить как полезный

Comment: Также непонятно почему ChangeCustomers вызывается только у Modified строк?

Comment: Это сделано для того что каждый раз когда изменилась одно только значение не сохранять всех, а только измененное

Comment: Я понимаю так что идет просмотр каждой строки таблицы. и если строка изменялась. То снова подаем ее на изменение. Ерунда какая-то получается.

Comment: Причем как я понимаю подаваться должна не строка из базы а строка с уже желаемыми изменениями. А подается получается строка из базы

Comment: Нет тут никакой ерунды. Это статичные методы вызываемые из приложения. Если вызвали сохранить таблицу то вызывается второй если строку то первый

Comment: Объясните, пожалуйста, подается на проверку modified строка из базы или  строка с желаемыми изменениями?

Comment: Изменения приходят не из базы. Из базы приходят данные потом они изменяются в приложении. Приложение проверяет изменились ли они и сохраняет.

Comment: а сохраняет в базу?

Comment: Проверяет и сохраняет в базу.